Issues with packet sniffing with airodump
I tried to do the following airodump command:
airodump-ng wlan0

I got the following output.
CH  1 ][ Elapsed: 1 min ][ 2024-11-19 04:13 ][ interface wlan0 down
BSSID      PWR  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH   MB   ENC CIPHER  AUTH ESSID
BSSID      STATION         PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Notes  Probes

I was not able to view the list of active routers in the vicinity. Any explanation to this?

Are there any routers in the near vicinity? It would sure help to put your network card into monitor-mode! You can use airmon-ng.

Yes it is in monitor mode. There are routers in the vicinity.
